# How to limit clipboard size in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, clipboard

I am trying to limit clipboard size to 100 kb of remote system, to disallow users from copy and pasting large from remote system to their locals. How can I do that on remote system?

Comment: Are you sure they are copy.pasting between systems? What is their "local" systel and how to they connect to the remove? (add answer to your initial question).

Comment: Copying between systems means, copying from server to local machine via clipboard. If somehow we can limit the size of clipboard on server system, we can protect copying of large files to the localsystem.

Comment: If you think cut/paste on the screen, then the copy is from something which is already in the local machine buffer to the local clipboard. And that could be scripted. You could try to educe the amount of data transferred per session, but this would have other impacts. But if you don't trust people, don't give them access.